# Create a nested JSON with SQL in Db2

Tags: sql, arrays, json, db2-400

I have actually a JSON extracted from a table

```
select  json_object ('ITEM_ID' value Trim(PRDC), 
                     'ITEM_DESC' value TRIM(DESC),
                                       ) JSONData
from my_file
```

I Obtein this:

```
[{"ITEM_ID":"PRODUCT_01","ITEM_ITDESC":"DESC_01"},
 {"ITEM_ID":"PRODUCT_02","ITEM_ITDESC":"DESC_02"},
...
]
```

Now I need  an extraction like this...

```
[{"ITEM_ID":"PRODUCT_01","ITEM_ITDESC":"DESC_01", "ITEM_TIERPRICE": [
  {"QTY": 5, "PRICE": 7.0000},
  {"QTY": 10, "PRICE": 6.0000}
]},
{"ITEM_ID":"PRODUCT_02","ITEM_ITDESC":"DESC_02", "ITEM_TIERPRICE": [
  {"QTY": 5, "PRICE": 6.0000},
  {"QTY": 10, "PRICE": 5.0000}
]}
...
]
```

But I don't know how to obtain it.
The ITEM_TIERPRICE is like

```
SELECT QTY, PRICE FROM PRICE_TABLE WHERE ITEM = MY_ITEM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want an JSON object that includes an array of JSON objects..

Have you looked at the examples in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-json-arrayagg)?

This one in particular

```
select 
  json_object(
      'department number' value deptno
      , 'department name' value deptname
      , 'employee list' 
         value json_arrayagg(
                 json_object(
                     'last name' value lastname
                     , 'employee id' value empno
                 )
               order by lastname
          )
       )
  from dept
       left outer join emp
         on deptno = workdept
  where deptno like 'D%'
  group by deptno
           ,deptname;
```

Note the use of
`JSON_OBJECT(JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT()))`

Comment: I miss this part! It's work! Thank you